# Using a partially filled array with JList

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a project that uses JList filled by a partially filled array.  This results in empty elements in the JList. What is the best way to eliminate that from happening.?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your partially filled array and you can't change that, use a `Vector` by filling it with all of the elements of the array that are not null and then assign it to the `JList`.

Otherwise, store your objects in a collection instead of an `array` and invoke the `toArray` method on it when you create the `JList` or assign it with `JList#setListData`.